# Convexity of inf convolution

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact convex set in a normed linear space, and suppose $f: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex, i.e.
\begin{equation}
f((1-\lambda)x_1 + \lambda x_2, (1-\lambda)y_1 + \lambda y_2) \leq (1-\lambda)f(x_1,y_1) + \lambda f(x_2,y_2).
\end{equation}
Suppose $g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function which satisfies the relation
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \inf_{y \in X}\{f(x,y) + g(y)\}
\end{equation}
Is it necessarily true that $g$ is convex? It is well known that $\inf_{y \in X}f(x,y)$ is convex, but this same type of proof does not seem to work  here. On the other hand, the relation for $g$ is incredibly restrictive that one should be able to say something.

Comment: You cannot add elements of a compact metric space so convexity makes no sense. Perhaps you want X to  be a compact convex set in a normed linear space.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you are right, thanks, I have edited!